# UnicodeDecodeError with processing a csv

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, csv, unicode

Suddently a "UnicodeDecodeError" arises in a code of mine which worked yesterday.

> File
>   "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line
>   3284, in run_code
>       self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line
>   2021, in showtraceback
>       value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line
>   1379, in structured_traceback
>       self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line
>   1291, in structured_traceback
>       elist = self._extract_tb(tb)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line
>   1272, in _extract_tb
>       return traceback.extract_tb(tb)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\lib\traceback.py", line 72, in extract_tb
>       return StackSummary.extract(walk_tb(tb), limit=limit)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\lib\traceback.py", line 364, in extract
>       f.line
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\lib\traceback.py", line 286, in line
>       self._line = linecache.getline(self.filename, self.lineno).strip()
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
>       lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
>       return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\lib\linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
>       lines = fp.readlines()
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
>       (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position
>   2441: invalid start byte

```
import csv
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

dateiname_TDM = "./TDM_example_small.csv" 
dateiname_corpus = "./Topic_Modeling/Input_Data/corpus.mm" 
dateiname_dictionary = "./Topic_Modeling/Input_Data/dictionary.dict"

ids = {}
corpus = []

with open(dateiname_TDM, newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|') 
    documente = next(reader, None)[1:]
    for rownumber, row in enumerate(reader): 
        for index, field in enumerate(row):
            if index == 0:
                if rownumber > 0:
                    ids[rownumber-1] = field 
            else:
                if rownumber == 0:
                    corpus.append([])
                else:
                    try:
                        if field > 0:
                            corpus[index-1].append((rownumber-1, int(field)))
                    except ValueError:
                        corpus[index-1].append((rownumber-1, 0))
```

Comment: If your code hasn't changed since yesterday, maybe the input data have. Apparently the CSV file you're reading now wasn't encoded with UTF-8, but probably some 8-bit character set (eg. CP1252). Please also have a look at [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors), explaining how this is not quite enough information (we need to know what you think `byte 0xf6` should be interpreted as – "ö" maybe?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the what's at position 2441 I'm not entirely sure, but it is probably one of the following:

- A special, non-ascii/extended ascii character, in which case do `the_string.encode("UTF-8")` or when opening do `encoding = "UTF-8"` in the `open` function
- You have `\u` or `\U` somewhere and this makes the next characters read as part of a Unicode sequence so do `repr(the_string)` to add backslashes to nullify backslashes after (Probably not this one)
- You are reading a `bytes` object not a `str` object. Try opening it with `r+b` (read & write, bytes) in the `open` function

I've more or less thrown spaghetti at a wall but I hope this helps!